# To display the searched item in the same page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The following code present in srches_controller

```
def index
   @srches = Srch.all
   respond_to do |format|
     format.html # index.html.erb
     format.json { render :json => @srches }
end
. 
.
.
def search
    @srch=Srch.find(:all,
                :conditions => ["name LIKE ? OR address LIKE ?", "%#{params[:search]}%", "%#{params[:search]}%"])
end
```

The searched item is now displayed in the new search page.
But I need to display the searched item in the same index page.
What is the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass parameter `search` to index page and search your results with:

```
def index
  @srches = Srch.scoped
  if params[:search].present?
    @srches = @srches.where(['name LIKE ? OR address LIKE ?', "%#{params[:search]}%", "%#{params[:search]}%"])
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render :json => @srches }
  end
end
```

or you can set scope in your model:

```
scope :search, lambda{|query|
  if query.present?
    where(['name LIKE ? OR address LIKE ?', "%#{query}%", "%#{query}%"])
  end
}
```

and call it in controller with:

```
@srches = Srch.search(params[:search])
```

Comment: Thank you for the immediate response.

Answer (score 0):

You can use meta search gem for your index method, it looks some thing like this -

```
def index
   @srches = Srch.search(params[:search])
   respond_to do |format|
     format.html # index.html.erb
     format.json { render :json => @srches }
end
```

In this case if search parameters were present it will search in your table else it will return all the records from your table.